# ¿Cómo quitar las flechas de ordenamiento de un datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

He estado intentando quitar el filtro de ordenamiento que hace el `dataTable` por defecto en las columnas de la tabla y no he podido hasta el momento, sí alguien sabe, me ayudaría mucho!

Anexo el código que he intenta

```
var tableData = $('#table').DataTable( {
            scrollY: "400px",
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            columnDefs:[{
                targets: "_all",
                searchable: false
            }],
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 3
            }
        });
```

Adjunto captura de la tabla:

[image: Visualización de la tabla]

Comment: A cuales filtros te refieres?

Comment: El de la columnas, que es ordenar por columna

Comment: Una cosa es el filtro de búsqueda y otro es el ordenamiento por columna, ¿A cuál de ellos te refieres?

Comment: El ordenamiento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opcion que buscas es `sortable`:

```
var tableData = $('#table').DataTable( {
        scrollY: "400px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        columnDefs:[{
            targets: "_all",
            sortable: false
        }],
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 3
        }
    });
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: DaxTter77, si te funcionó la solución propuesta, recuerda aceptar la respuesta. De esta manera los dos obtienen reputación y servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

Define como falso la propiedad de [ordering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) al inicializar la tabla.

```
var tableData = $('#table').DataTable( {
            scrollY: "400px",
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            ordering: false,
            paging: false,
            columnDefs:[{
                targets: "_all",
                searchable: false
            }],
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 3
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso deseada que se quitaran esas flechas , y la propiedad que le coloque fue  **ordering: false,**

con el siguiente resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***********CODIGO*****************

```
            let tabFunctionalitiesEnterpriseTarificador = 
            $('#example-table').DataTable
                    ({
            info: false,
            ordering: false,
            
            "lengthChange": false,
            "language": {
                "search": "Buscar información",
               
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primera",
                    "last": "Ultima",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                },
                "emptyTable": "Sin historial"
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    orderable: false,
                    className: 'select-checkbox', //checked
                    targets: 0, // en la columna 0 el check
                    sortable: false

                }
            ],

            select: {
                style: 'single',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[2, 'asc']],  //columna 2 - ascendente 
            "pageLength": 5,
```